# PHP Session working process

Tags: php

I have several pages like index.php,login.php,logout.php ,edit.php etc.in a folder named admin.

I have created session in index.php and login.php and destroy the session in logout.php and they are workinhg fine.When I used to type in my browser "localhost/admin" then it shows the login page.so I come to know that they are working fine.But when I used to type in the browser "localhost/admin/edit.php" then also it shows the login page.I know its a good thing so that security will be good in my page.But my question is why it showing the login page when I used to access directly the edit.php page though I had not created any session or even destroy any session on that page.

Please help me to get rid out of this doubt.

And can you please explain me the concept of session like what is session and how its work.

Thank You.

Comment: Can you post the `edit.php`? And I'm confused, you said that you are okay with that behavior, yet you are doubting it.

Answer (score 0):

Please verify session on each page and session is available than Proceed the page otherwise redirect to Login page.

```
if (isset($_SESSION['sessionName'])) {
   // logged in
} else {
   // not logged in
}
```